# Homebrew issues installing Node & NPM

Tags: node.js, homebrew, zsh

OS - macOS Catalina - Version 10.15.2

I have used the bash shell in Mac and on my Windows 10 machine and have used apt-get for many installs. Recently (possibly after update) I have noticed that when I am in bash, I cannot run apt-get anymore.

```
[bash-3.2$ apt-get
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

This is odd because I've used apt-get through bash many many times on this machine. Attempting to familiarize with the zsh shell, I've installed homebrew successfully.

```
% brew -v
Homebrew 2.2.4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 57b7f; last commit 2020-01-24)
```

Looks good. Now time to load Node (which has always installed npm alongside)

```
% brew install node
Warning: node 13.7.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use 'brew link node' to link this version.

% brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.7.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
```

OK...

```
% brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.7.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.
```

So here is what I'm left with when I try to run node from zsh

```
% node -v
zsh: command not found: node
% npm -v
env: node: No such file or directory
```

If I try to run brew in sudo, it blocks root access, understood. If I try to install node from node's website I get this error

> "node-v12.14.1.pkg” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Does anyone with more experience in zsh and with homebrew have any idea how to get me into node in zsh?

I've really love to use packages like: `npm create-react-app`.

UPDATE from brew doctor

from brew doctor:

`Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.`
lists about 150 files, then

`Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run 'brew link' on these:
  node`

`Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with 'brew cleanup':`
i ran brew cleanup but get an error
`Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/JSONStream`

Comment: What does `brew doctor` say?

Comment: from brew doctor:

`Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.`
lists about 150 files, then

`Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  node`

`Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:`
i ran brew cleanup

Comment: Given that MacOS doesn't _have_ `apt-get`, how did you install it before? (and possibly: _why_ did you install it before? MacOS is not a debian flavour, homebrew is the general recommended package manager) Have you tried rerunning that installation? As for installing Node, this is one of those cases where you don't want to use brew, but [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), which does an infinitely better job at managing your node installations.

Comment: i cant remember but probably did a curl in bash and installed it. i definitely had apt-get **In BASH**

Comment: Sure, just wondering why you'd need it. Also in case you missed it, you really want `nvm` for Node, not `brew install node`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i gotcha, yeah MIke i was just used to bash and apt-get, never really used zsh or brew before this week. i am just a creature of habit trying to learn a new shell and homebrew.

Comment: heh, this is that one usecase where brew's actually the opposite of useful, although for virtually everything else it's pretty handy. How do you run the bash that you're showing can't find apt-get anymore? Just the standard applications -> utilities -> terminal?

Comment: yeah i have 5-6 shells installed, you just call them from the command line. zsh, bash, etc.

Comment: i never had a clean `brew doctor` run,  but after playing around I figured this out. i've uninstalled node with brew, then cleaned up all the node or npm folders in local ie: `/usr/local/include/node`. now i get : `% brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING: this solution may be dangerous if you have anything important in `/usr/local` or if you have configurations in homebrew that you don't want to lose. If you are just using ZSH and are going to be primarily using homebrew as a package manager, this is probably a safe bet.

Thanks everyone for the help. There are many things going on here so for anyone who is having similar issues.

- uninstall homebrew `uninstall homebrew`
- erase the entire contents of /usr/local
- install homebrew using ruby

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

- install wget `brew install wget`
- install node `brew install node`
- check the brew install `brew doctor`

`Your system is ready to brew.`

- check node `node -v`

`v13.7.0`

- check npm `npm -v`

`6.13.6`

- enter node `node`
- live happily ever after

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on the React project and faced the same issue. I solved this way not deleting homebrew just deleting a current node and reinstall.

`brew install node`

and it's working with these kids ;)

`node -v`

`npm -v`